# Can i create custom queries in Where and Case statements from dynamic array in Kusto Query?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-analytics

I have a `requests` datatable with `url`, `name`, `timestamp` columns, to which i add another computed column `operationType`.

I want to filter and query `requests` based on defined dynamic object attributes `data`, in order to obtain Operations and their usage count, like this:

```
operationType    | Counts
-------------------------
1.1 Operation A  | 2400
-------------------------
1.2 Operation B  | 1500
```

What i have:

```
let daysAgo = 100d;
let data = dynamic([
{
    'searchKey': 'url',
    'searchOperator': 'contains',
    'searchValue': 'AjaxContent?option=something',
    'operationName': '1.1 Operation A'
},
{
    'searchKey': 'name',
    'searchOperator': 'matches regex',
    'searchValue': 'POST /api/repo/\\d+/filters',
    'operationName': '1.2 Operation B'
}]);

let req = requests
| where (timestamp >= ago(daysAgo))
| where 

//Issue #1: I want data[0].searchKey to be used as the requests column name
data[0].searchKey contains data[0].searchValue 
//url contains data[0].searchValue //works

//Issue #2: 'doesn't work, error 'matches regex' operator requires string arguments
or name matches data[1].searchValue
//or name matches regex 'POST /api/repo/\\d+/filters' //works

| extend operationType= 
            case(name == data[2].searchValue, data[2].operationName,
                    url contains data[0].searchValue, data[0].operationName
                    'Other - please check'  ) 
| order by timestamp desc;

req | summarize Counts = count() by operationType
```

The ideal would be to create a custom query, like bellow (and maybe even looping through dynamic array attributes `data`) (Q #3):

```
requests | where data[0].searchKey data[0].searchOperator data[0].searchValue
```

In the same context, ideal would also be to extend the computed `operationType` column to be somehow custom created (Q #4):

```
requests
| where
...
| extend operationType= case(url contains data[0].searchValue, data[0].operationName,
                             name matches regex data[0].searchValue, data[0].operationName)
```

or

```
requests
| where
...
| extend operationType= case(data[0].searchKey data[0].searchOperator data[0].searchValue, data[0].operationName,
                             data[1].searchKey data[1].searchOperator data[0].searchValue, data[0].operationName)
```

1. Can dynamic value be used as the datatable column name in a `where` statement (Issue #1)?
2. Can dynamic value be used as right hand in the `matches regex` statement (Issue #2)?
3. Can create a dynamically custom query `where` statement, looping through dynamic array (Q #3)?
4. Can a computed extended column be custom created in a `case` statement (Q #4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Can dynamic value be used as the datatable column name in a where statement?

> Yes. Please check : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/columnifexists
>   Example showing column_ifexists() and 'matches regex'

```
datatable (a:string, b:string)
['1', '2']
| where column_ifexists('a', '') matches regex '1'
```

2) Can dynamic value be used as right hand in the matches regex statement?

> To some extent. In general, only constant values are supported, so you can't use row-context (where regex will vary for each row). You can, however, use toscalar() to calculate constant regular expressions as a sub-query, and use those as an argument to 'matches regex'. 
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/toscalarfunction

3) Can create a dynamically custom query where statement, looping through dynamic array?

> No. Dynamic KQL queries are not supported at this moment.

4) Can a computed extended column be custom created in a case statement?

> Yes, as long as you use techniques described in answer #1 and #2, and not running into limitations of #3.

Comment: Thank you, @Alexander Sloutsky!
How can i integrate your ideas and filter `requests` based on `datatable` specific row values? 
Something like: 
    `requests | where dataTableVar[0].searchKey dataTableVar[0].searchOperator dataTableVar[0].searchValue`

Comment: I guess, the closest you can come is: let dataTableVar = dynamic([{ "searchOperator": "contains", "searchValue": "value1_1"}]);
let predicate = (T:(*), col:string, op:string, value:string)
{
let _regex = case(op == 'contains', value,
op == 'has', strcat(@'\b', value, @'\b'),
op == 'equals', strcat(@'^', value, '$'),
'_todo_');
T | where column_ifexists(col, '') matches regex toscalar(_regex) 
};
datatable(Col1:string, Col2:string)
['value1_1', 'value_2_1']
| invoke predicate(col='Col1', tostring(dataTableVar[0].searchOperator), tostring(dataTableVar[0].searchValue))